# Issues with Item in Object being 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, grouping

I'm trying to sort and group an array of objects. But, I am running into an issue where calling the key name 'Driver', is returning 'undefined'.

The code is as follows:

```
let hos = [
    {
        "Driver": "test-000000",
        "Date": "3/15/2020",
        "Status": "Off-Duty",
        "Time": "12:00 AM",
        "": "",
        "__1": "",
        "__2": ""
    },
    {
        "Driver": "test-000000",
        "Date": "3/16/2020",
        "Status": "Off-Duty",
        "Time": "12:00 AM",
        "": "",
        "__1": "",
        "__2": ""
    }
];

let hosByDriver = [];

hos.forEach((item, index) => {
// If the current item.Driver string match the previous or next '.Driver' push it to an array inside hosByDriver[targetedDriver] else push it by itself
    if (item.Driver == hos[index + 1].Driver || item.Driver == hos[index - 1].Driver) {
        hosByDriver[item.Driver].push(item);
    } else {
        hosByDriver[item.Driver].push(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: Either `hos[index + 1].Driver`  or `hos[index - 1].Driver` can be trying to access a value that is `undefined` on the `hos` array particularly when `index === 0` or `index === hos.length - 1`, which will happen twice when iterating over an array, once per condition.

Comment: `hosByDriver` is array, not object. I think the error is here: `hosByDriver[item.Driver]`

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You are doing same thing inside both if & else statements.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys!

I've found out you can call an array index by string instead of a index value. Thus, why I was trying that. Unfortunately, I lost the ability to push using an object. 

Not sure why I'm running into issues with this, seems to be basic js..

@palash, Essentially, if there is no other entry before or after the current 'item', it just pushes it to the array. ie. The driver was off that day, the Status would be only Off-duty with no other entries

Comment: You are right. It does do the same thing. I gotta rewrite this...

Comment: @LiveBacteria What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: I edited the post to show my intentions.

So in short, I have a list of drivers and their hours of duty status states individually, given via an array of objects. I wanted to create an array that groups each driver by name along with their respective duty statuses. E.g. `[{DriverName: [driverHoSObject provided by the hos json object]}]`

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration **(index is 0)** your code looks like below

```js
hos.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(index);
    // neither hos[1] nor hos[-1] do exist -> undefined
    if (item.Driver == hos[0+1] || item.Driver == hos[0-1].Driver) {
        hosByDriver[item.Driver].push(item);
    } else {
        hosByDriver[item.Driver].push(item);
    }
});
```

So it crashes at very first round.  `hos[0-1].Driver` evaluates to `undefined.Driver`. You can get around this using **&&**.

*Note: array[-1] is not invalid syntax*

```js
hos[index - 1] && hos[index - 1].Driver
```

Also, item.Driver is a string. Arrays are usually indexed by number. I think you meant to use an Object instead:

```js
let hosByDriver = {};

hos.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(index);
  if (hos[index - 1] && (item.Driver === hos[index + 1] ||  item.Driver === hos[index - 1].Driver)) {
    //hosByDriver[item.Driver] = [];
    //hosByDriver[item.Driver].push(item);
  } else {
    hosByDriver[item.Driver] = [];
    hosByDriver[item.Driver].push(item);
  }
});
```

I also changed .map to .forEach, because you are not returning a new Array, which map excepts. forEach is the equivalent if you just want to iterate.

Im only guessing here what you want to achieve, if you provide more details, i can provide a better solution. Take a look at this codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-3h2n9

I think you need to read a little about the basics of JavaScript (like data types, loops, etc). That said, keep learning! :)

**Update:**
If I understood correctly, you wan't to group Drivers in hosByDriver having the same name stored in hos. Use-Case would be to access all items of a driver like `hosByDriver['test-000000']` and avoid iterating over the whole arrayover and over again, which makes sense.

You can achieve this easily by doing following

```js
let hosByDriver = {};

hos.forEach(item => {

  // if item or item.Driver could be not what you expect you could check with 
  // item && item.Driver && typeof item.Driver === "string" 
  // in your if statement
  if(!hosByDriver[item.Driver]){ 
  // set hosByDriver[item.Driver] to empty array if it is undefined (more precisly: if its [falsy][1], meaning either 0, "", undefined, null ,NaN or false
    hosByDriver[item.Driver] = []
  }
  // append item to array at hosByDriver[item.Driver]
  // either empty or holding previous items
  hosByDriver[item.Driver].push(item);
});
```

*Info:*

*In JavaScript Arrays ares really just Objects(key/value pairs).  If you like to know more about this you can watch [JavaScript: Understanding the Weird Parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv_5Zv5c-Ts). Arrays are special case where you access a value with a number beginning from zero, even though i think you can put strings anyway - cause JavaScript is very forgiving - i would not recommend that. When it gets more complex, you will have a hard-time debugging.*

*It is also not recommended to use ==, instead use === to prevent the JS-Engine attempting to do type-conversion. E.g. `0 == ""` yields `true`. This can also cause you a lot of trouble.*

Comment: Hey bud, thanks for the reply!

In my current list of drivers and their duty statuses, there are about 2000 entries for the past week, so I can see why the demo code would fail.

Additionally, I realise I missed the '.Driver' portion on the initial if statement. 

So, `hos[ index + 1 ].Driver `.

In your solution you noted `    hosByDriver[item.Driver] = [];
    hosByDriver[item.Driver].push(item);` Essentially, the way I had the code was like a constructor, ie. If the targeted Driver key is not an array, create one for the .push(item) to work on

Comment: hey you're right. the code would store just the last Driver. See the Update-Section in my answer. I also updated the codesandbox.